Pressing Back button still calls ondisconnect - SignalR
I have 2 pages
ReviewPage.cshtml => SubmitAnswer.cshtml
The SubmitAnswer only has the signalr.js and will reconnect on disconnect
But when I navigate back to ReviewPage, the SubmitAnswer page will disconnect and try to reconnect while loading the ReviewPage and causes error due to it failed to get a clientid/sessionid on the ReviewPage
The problem is, this doesn't happen on my local machine and our qa, it only happens on prod. In my local machine and qa, it doesn't disconnect and try to reconnect before loading ReviewPage, but only on prod.
Is it a server configuration or a bug in signalr?
